# Is it possible to share Eclipse through Remote Desktop session

Tags: remote-desktop, eclipse

Having issue with using eclipse:

```
the workspace in use message comes up.
```

Is there way to share eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one Eclipse process can access the workspace at any one time. So you have these options:

1. One user only watches the other develop
2. You copy the workspace
3. You save the projects in a version control system like Mercurial or Subversion so every developer can get their own copy and merge their work with the rest of the team.

Comment: How to copy workspace? We do share same user credentials.

Comment: Copy the workspace folder and delete the folder ".metadata". Export the preferences in Eclipse, start a second copy, switch the workspace (it should ask during startup; otherwise use the item in the File menu) and import the prefs.

Comment: I did that, but having issue with showing projects in Project Explorer. None of them is visible. Thank you.

Comment: I end up with using get project from svn

Comment: You must import the files again. Just select the new workspace folder in the "Import Existing Project" wizard and it should show you all projects at once.